# How to implement dist in R

Tags: r, distance, heatmap

I have a distance function which looks like this

```
sed <- function(x, y){
x <- x / sum(x)
y <- y / sum(y)

x <- x[y > 0]
y <- y[y > 0]
y <- y[x > 0]
x <- x[x > 0]

xy <- x + y
a <- x / xy
b <- y / xy

w <- xy / 2
2 * prod(a^(a*w) * b^(b*w)) - 1
```

}

and I have some data that looks like this:

```
> head(x)
             x         y
[1,] 0.5836377 0.8120142
[2,] 0.4642154 0.8857223
[3,] 0.8707579 0.4917120
[4,] 0.4688734 0.8832654
[5,] 0.8105051 0.5857316
[6,] 0.6409956 0.7675446
```

Where each row is a point with x and y coordinates. So sed calculates the distance between rows.

I would like to plot a heatmap using my distance function but I get the following error, how can I fix this?

```
> heatmap(as.matrix(x), distfun=as.dist(sed))
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

Comment: I don't think you want to use `as.dist` on `sed`. It's expecting the function itself.

Comment: that gives a different error: Error in y/sum(y) : 'y' is missing

Comment: Yeah, I was sort of expecting more things to go wrong. Note that the default value for `distfun` is `dist`, which accepts the entire matrix as an input and returns the entire distance matrix. Chances are, `heatmap` is expecting `sed` to behave similarly.

Comment: Are you sure, you want your function `sed` to generate a single value?

Comment: yes, sed is a function over two vectors which gives the distance between them as a real

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `distfun` argument expects a function that will return an object that is of class `"dist"` as returned by `dist()`. Your function computes the distance between two vectors not the entire set of dissimilarities for each pair of observations. It doesn't return the right type of object and nor can it without all the scaffolding required to iterate over all pairs of rows in the input data.

Fear ye not though as help is at hand via the **proxy** [package available on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proxy/index.html). This allows you to provide exactly the sort of function you have written and it provides all the scaffolding required to generate the dissimilarity matrix.

You need to register your function with **proxy** before you can use it in anger:

```
## create a new distance measure
mydist <- function(x,y) x * y

## create a new entry in the registry with two aliases
pr_DB$set_entry(FUN = mydist, names = c("mydist"))
```

Just replace `mydist` with your function name and you can give it whatever name you want when entering it into the proxy database. Continuing this example, you'd then use `dist()` to compute the dissimilarity matrix:

```
dist(X, method = "mydist")
```

To see if this will suit your needs

```
install.packages("proxy")
require("proxy")
```

Then read `?dist` and `?pr_DB`.